# How to use the syncStatusChanged property

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

So how to use the **[syncStatusChanged](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Datastore.syncStatusChanged)** property of the **[Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore)**. I want to signal the user the sync status. A little example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using jQuery that updates an HTML element called `status`:

```
client.getDatastoreManager().openDefaultDatastore(function (error, datastore) {
    ...

    $('#status').text('Synchronized');
    datastore.syncStatusChanged.addListener(function () {
        $('#status').text(
            datastore.getSyncStatus().uploading
            ? 'Pending...'
            : 'Synchronized'
        );
    });

    ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a case for downloading too?

Comment: Not that I see, no: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Datastore.getSyncStatus.

Comment: Beh. The movile SDKs have more details in their sync status. I guess while data is being downloaded the app just isn't responsive. :-)